# Use VLOOKUP but detach the value from the lookup once it is in the cell/looked up

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following:
1 Access file with a big list of items that people can order.
1 Excel file with 2 tabs.
In the 2nd tab of the Excel file I import the Access table.
For each row I have a dropdown list in the first column with the values of the first column of the access table.
In the 2nd column of the first tab I use VLOOKUP to show the price linked to the item of the first column.
In the 3rd column of the first tab the user can fill in an amount.

**Here's the catch:**
in the 4th column of the first Excel Tab I want to show a total so B * C. Nothing hard about that. But I want this value to NEVER CHANGE.
So even if the Access database is updated I do not want the value of the already calculated cells of column 4 to change.

I know it seems pretty unlogical but I really need this.
Any suggestions? Is there a formula that I am missing?

EDIT from post:
The file is to be used be other people than myself. If paste special can be done automatically as in like a formula it would help but that doens't exist or I haven't found it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I needs to go automatic. Paste Special is not really an option since that is a manual command :(

Comment: I think you don't quite understand. The file is to be used be other people than myself. They are able to have 20 items = 20 rows and they would have to use paste special themselves. If paste special can be done automatically as in like a formula it would help but that doens't exist or I haven't found it.

Comment: hmmm ... you don't mention any of this though.

Answer (score 0):

If the formula is linked to a connection (e.g. OLAP cube, a table that is linked to an Access table) then remove the connection before sending the sheet out. See [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WERO.png).
If you distribute the workbooks to people who do not have access to the data itself (not on your network) the issue will solve itself, take away that some dummies will complain about their data <strike>disappearing</strike> not refreshing.

The formula you're asking for would *refer to itself* once it has a value, confer circular reference.

If used by your close enivronment you might want to have a VBA snipplet insert your formula and then do the PasteSpecial method automatically (you'll have to enable macros on each of the computers involved in this case).